# Page object in testng error (java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to implement the concept of Page Object using TestNG. I created a **BrowserFactory class** that has the information to initialize the browser.
I also created a class called **LogSystemPage** that has the information of the screen elements that I need to interact with.

Lastly, I created a test class called **ValidateStatusTestNG** that "calls" the **BrowserFactory** and **LogSystemPage** classes.

When I try to run the test method called **logarSystem**, the Eclipse console displays the following error message: java.lang.NullPointerException.
Following is the code, the error message and the images.

```
public class BrowserFactory {

static WebDriver driver;

public static WebDriver startBrowser(String url) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(url);


    return driver;
}}

public class LogarSistemaPage {

private static WebDriver driver;

public WebDriver logarSistema(WebDriver driver) {

    driver.findElement(By.id("matricula_I")).sendKeys("844502");
    driver.findElement(By.id("senha_I")).sendKeys("Pw34Jdt#*");
    driver.findElement(By.id("bt_entrar")).click();

    return driver;

}}

public class ValidarStatusTestNG {

static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    BrowserFactory b = new BrowserFactory();
    b.startBrowser("http://10.5.9.45/BKOMais_S86825EstrategiaBackOfficeClaroFixo/");

}

@Test
public void logarSistema(){

    LogarSistemaPage s = new LogarSistemaPage();
    s.logarSistema(driver);

}

@AfterClass
public static void closeBrowser() {

    //driver.quit();

}}
```

[image: TestNGErro_1]

[image: TestNGErro_2]

[image: TestNGErro_3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

driver =b.startBrowser("http://10.5.9.45/BKOMais_S86825EstrategiaBackOfficeClaroFixo/")
You need to assign the return value of method returning driver to driver.

```
    @BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    BrowserFactory b = new BrowserFactory();
driver =b.startBrowser("http://10.5.9.45/BKOMais_S86825EstrategiaBackOfficeClaroFixo/");

}

@Test
public void logarSistema(){

    LogarSistemaPage s = new LogarSistemaPage();
    s.logarSistema(driver);

}
```

That should do the work.